# Question on Stack Overflow infected with a trojan?

Tags: support

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265194/what-does-this-malicious-php-do) which is about malicious [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code when suddenly I had a notice from my virusscanner ([Avast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avast!)) that it had blocked a possible infection. After just closing the notice I saw that I was not able to access that single question anymore. For a couple of seconds I couldn't even reach Stack Overflow, but after a couple of refreshes it got back.

When trying to view the question I just get this:

[image]

(Translation: No data received)

The notice I get from my virusscanner:

[image]

So I'm kind of wondering what was in that question?

Comment: I think it triggered on this link `http://www.sendspace.com/file/491mvr` but be aware: The author claims that it has the virus code.

Comment: What a silly virus scanner. There is nothing on that page that can infect you; the `sendspace.com` link still requires *two clicks* and explicit installation / running with PHP before it has even a remote chance to infect your machine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm, looks like my virus scanner is a bit overprotective then. Thnx for the clarification though, I was just curious what was in the question since I wasn't able to see it.

Comment: That's weird, the proxy of my society was blocking stack overflow during (around) the last hour. That was a terrible hour :(

Comment: What a horrible virus.  It has changed all the text in your browser from English into some alien moonspeak!  I feel so bad for you.  My condolences.

Comment: That's clearly a false positive, report this on the anti virus support forums.

Comment: @Will that be Dutch :). Indeed alien, but probably worse.